# HttpConnectionParams odd syntax error

Tags: android, syntax

I'm sure there's some simple fix I'm just not seeing but for some reason the following code:

```
private HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams(); 
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
private Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Gives syntax errors, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si61l.png

Please help, I have no idea why these are syntactically incorrect, it's attempting to tell me I need to delete the brackets.

Comment: We really need to see more of your code - if this code is inside a function the private keyword is illegal. If it is in some kind of declaration (like a class definition) then you can;t execute code (such as setSOTimeout) (also the actual error messages would be great)

Comment: import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a function (`setConnectionTimeout()`) in a class body, not in a method body.

Move the`HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);` and `HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);` to some method (constructor on example), on example:

```
private HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

public void initialize () {
  HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams(); 
  int timeoutConnection = 3000;
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
  int timeoutSocket = 5000;
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
}

// rest of the code
```

Additionally, why do you need two instances of `HttpClient`?